# getting std::bad_alloc error ; How to cross-verify that OS is really running out of memory

Tags: c++, memory-management, memory-leaks, operating-system

I have a C++ program/Linux, which within 2-3 seconds of running starts spitting error `std::bad alloc` on a 32GB RAM (and gets restarted by wrapper caller). What I really care about is to solve this problem, but I would like to go step by step and build up my confidence in my understanding of the problem.

It looks like the system is not able to allocate memory for a `new` request (this would happen when the OS has run out of memory). While the program is running, on another terminal I run the `sar` command with the smallest interval possible (1 second), but I see that `kbcached` is ~24GB memory. Why is the OS not able to release the caching and make that memory available to the `new` request? Either 1 sec is too much time (in comparison to how fast programs run) or I am doing something wrong here.

Basically I would like to cross-verify and pin-point that the OS is indeed running out of memory and thus is not able to allocate memory, and then take things from this point on. How to do it?

Ideally, I would like to have the system statistics right at the point when memory allocation fails, like how much caching, total used up memory etc.

Comment: Just a note.. it has nothing to do with how RAM you have, it depends on how much free memory is present in process virtual memory address space. I don't know the command to check the process virtual memory allocation though.

Comment: I guess this will be OS-specific.

Comment: How much memory did your process allocate? What constraints does your process have? Is it 32 bit?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan : How to know, how much memory did the process allocate? Do you mean adding a debug statement to print how much memory is requested along with each 'new' call? The process is 32-bit.

Comment: A 32-bit process only has a 4GB address space. Can you do a 64-bit build?

Comment: @Blastfurnace : thanks for the pointer. Working on this clue.

Comment: @p2pnode: From the description you have given, I really doubt you are running out of memory. For me it looks like you are trying to do `new[]` with a number which is not initialized, in that case it will be some random number and new fails.

Comment: @Naveen : Actually the way my program works is that it works on a config file containing list of items to process. It is able to succesfully process 15 or so items. When I add 2 more items, that's when it runs out of memory, so I would think that basic correctness of program is okay.

Comment: @Blastfurnace, does Linux give you the entire 4GB? I know Windows won't.

Comment: @MarkRansom, I'm not sure but I think the Linux kernel reserves 1GB for its own use (probably a tunable setting). I know a 32-bit Windows user-mode process only gets 2GB (3GB with some fiddling).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you actually want to see how your process's memory is allocated, you could set a breakpoint with `gdb` for when the exception is thrown.  When it is, inspect the process with a tool like [pmap](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pmap), which can show you additional information about how the process uses memory.

If that's too primitive (and it quickly will be, `pmap` is pretty primitive), [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) includes Massif and many other utilities for diagnosing memory usage, CPU utilization, and other runtime problems.

Comment: Notably (in this case), the valgrind massif tool. Massif tracks allocations and allows one to get a graph of the memory consumption on a timeline; and for each snapshot, identifies where the allocations came from.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Maybe your comment should be an answer on its own?

Comment: @RedX: Nothing else to say, so I'll let Steven add the details to his own answer if he find them worth it.